# Strings Python (función que reciba dos parámetros)

Tags: python

Escribe una función que reciba dos parámetros: un texto y una letra. La función deberá imprimir la cadena, pero en cada letra diferente de “letra” deberá escribir asteriscos.

Ejemplo:

```
cadena = "This makes array operations faster but less safe"
letra = "a"
```

La función debe imprimir

```
******a****a**a******a*******a***************a**
```

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Para formular una buena pregunta, es mejor que incluyas los codigos ó metodos que ha probado para resolver esta problema. Hacen la pregunta mas bien recibida y ayudarán a la comunidad para dar la respuesta correcta. Tambien puede leer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [guia para preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Creo que esto serviría:

```
texto="This makes array operations faster but less safe"
letra="a"

def procesar(texto,letra):
    cadena=""
    if(len(letra)==1):
        for x in texto:
            if(x!=letra):
                cadena=cadena+"*"
            elif x==" ":
                cadena=cadena+" "
            else:
                cadena=cadena+x
    return cadena
print(procesar(texto,letra))
```

Answer (score 1):

El enunciado parece de una tarea académica. Por tanto la mejor solución depende de qué te hayan explicado hasta ahora, pues entiendo que no deberías usar en la respuesta características del lenguaje que aún no te hayan sido explicadas.

Sospecho que se espera que lo resuelvas mediante bucles, condiciones y operadores de concatenación. En esta línea la solución de @Santiago sería lo que buscas (excepto que su solución respeta los espacios pero tu enunciado no pide que hagas eso).

Por dar una solución diferente, más eficiente pero que usa características avanzadas del lenguaje, como expresiones generadoras, expresiones condicionales (o ternarias) y el método `str.join()` aquí hay otra forma, que da una idea de lo conciso y expresivo que puede llegar a ser Python:

```
def procesar(texto, letra):
   return "".join(c if c==letra else "*" for c in texto)
```

La expresión generadora `XXX for c in texto` causa internamente una iteración en la que `c` va tomando cada uno de los valores (caracteres) en el texto. Y para cada uno de esos valores evalúa la expresión `XXX`. Cada vez que se evalúa `XXX` se "genera" un nuevo valor para una colección. Al final, todos los elementos de esa colección se pasan como parámetro a  `"".join()`, que crea con ellos una cadena concatenándolos todos.

En este caso, la expresión `XXX` es `c if c==letra else "*"`. Esto es lo que se llama una expresión condicional (o ternaria), que equivaldría en C a `(c==letra)?c:"*"`. El resultado de evaluar esa expresión será o bien `c`, o bien `*`. Cuál de los dos depende de si la condición `c==letra` es cierta o no. Si es cierta, la expresión dará como resultado `c` (es decir, la misma letra que venía del texto), pero si es falsa dará `"*"`. Si por ejemplo `letra` era `"a"`, sólo cuando `c` sea una "a" el resultado es `c`. Por tanto todo lo que no sea `"a"` se cambia por `"*"`.

Así pues la expresión generadora va generando en este caso una serie de caracteres `"*"` y `"a"`, que finalmente `"".join()` concatena en una sola cadena, que es lo que se retorna. En una sola línea hemos descrito la funcionalidad deseada.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mismo pero con expresiones regulares:

```
import re
def procesar(texto, letra):
    return re.sub(f'[^{letra}]', '*', texto)
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución sencilla podría ser reemplazar los caracteres si son diferentes a la letra que quieres mediante `replace()`:

```
cadena = 'This makes array operations faster but less safe'
letra = 'a'

def reemplazar(texto, letra):
    for s in texto:
        if s != letra:
            texto = texto.replace(s, '*')
    return texto

print(reemplazar(cadena, letra))

# Salida: ******a****a**a******a*******a***************a**
```